# What does [] mean here?

Tags: perl

```
$self->[UTF8] = $conf->{utf8};
```

Never seen such code before.

What does `[]` mean here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case, the object `$self` is implemented as a blessed array reference rather than the far more common method of using a blessed hash reference. The syntax `$foo->[42]` accesses a single element from an array reference. Presumably, `UTF8` is a constant that returns a numeric index into the array.

You see this idiom sometimes when people become convinced (usually incorrectly) that hash lookups on object attributes result in significant overhead and try to prematurely optimize their code.

Comment: Array-based objects have at least two benefits: No typos in indexes since constants are used for the indexes. No multiple inheritance, forcing the use of roles.

Comment: It's *probably* blessed, given the name `$self`, but it could be just an ordinary accursed array reference.

Comment: friedo, are you sure that this is incorrect. I've done benchmarks--of course that savings gets wiped away with a method dispatch, if any.

Comment: Axeman, that's my point. Array lookups will be faster than hash lookups, but that's not where the bottlenecks in your code will be. So it's usually better to optimize for clarity and use standard idioms rather than clever tricks which won't actually help your program's speed.

Answer (score 3):

The `[]` implies that `$self` is a reference to a list/array (assuming the code works).  This looks a bit odd, though, as list indexes should be numeric.

Comment: The `UTF8` is probably a constant. We do this type of thing for implementing records/classes in perl. Use an arrayref as your object and constants for the indexes. Safer and more efficient than using hashes.

Comment: @Sodved: I kinda thought `UTF8` might be a constant.  It almost looks like a bug, though.  Part of why i don't think i'd ever use an array reference as an object like that.